# Why RestartResponseException in exception hanler doesn't redirect to other page?

Tags: java, wicket

I use RestartResponseException in exception handler (IRequestCycleListener) for redirection on login page and it doesn't work. I see exception in logs but no changes in UI.

```
        @Override
        public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception ex) {
            if (couldNotLock) {
                getSessionStore().invalidate(cycle.getRequest());
                throw new RestartResponseException(LoginPage.class);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: What is the actual behavior when it does not work ? Which page do you see ? Do you see a redirect response (status code == 302) in the DevTools > Network tab ?

Comment: Sorry, i've written wrong. Without session invalidation (only with RestartResponseException) page is refreshed with code 200 but not redirected, i see same page as before. 

With session invalidation, page is not refreshed, i don't see any requests in devtools. I see page as before. If i use F5 i see login page but it is not redirectio (still no requests in devtools)

Answer (score 0):

Even with your extra information in the question's comment it is still not clear what kind of problem you face.

I will try to guess: your LoginPage checks whether the user is already logged in and just redirects to the landing/home page of your application.

To fix that you need to invalidate the whole Session:

```
@Override
public IRequestHandler onException(RequestCycle cycle, Exception ex) {
    if (couldNotLock) {
       Session.get().invalidate();    // !!!
       throw new RestartResponseException(LoginPage.class);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it and got same result, i still see home page, but after clicking any button or refreshing page by F5 page changed to login page. I expected getting login page without additional actions like clicking or refreshing. I think RestartResponseException doesn't work cuz i change it for experiment on NullPointerException and got same result, i conclude page changing was caused by session invalidation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to throw `new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(LoginPage.class)` instead of RestartResponseException

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried and didn't see any difference from RestartResponseException. Still have no redirection.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps You can modify the page's URL with javascript.

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forScript("window.history.pushState(\"object or string\", \"" + pageTitle + "\", \"" + pageUrl + "\")"));
}
```

for AJAX:

```
    AjaxRequestTarget target = optional.get();
    target.prependJavaScript("window.history.pushState(\"object or string\", \"" + pageTitle + "\", \"" + pageUrl + "\")");
```

Comment: It's interesting idea but how to implement it in my exception handler (IRequestCycleListener)? I suppose i can't.

Comment: You can override renderHead() in your LoginPage class so that it will always set the correct url.